I keep getting this Error [PrivateRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
I'm trying to use routing and I literally have no idea of what's going on
this the app code
App.js
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom"
import { AuthProvider } from './context/AuthContext'
import './app.css'
import Dashboard from './views/Dashboard'
import PrivateRoute from "./utils/PrivateRoute"
import Home from './Components/Home/Home'
import Main from './Components/Main/Main'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar'
import Footer from './Components/Footer/Footer'
import Loginpage from './views/Loginpage'
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Navbar/>
        <Routes>
          <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Loginpage/>}/>
        </Routes>
        <Home/>
        <Main/>
        <Footer/>
     </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
 

this is the private route code
`PrivateRoute.js
import {Route, Navigate} from "react-router-dom"
import {useContext} from "react"
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthContext"


const PrivateRoute = ({children, ...rest}) => {
    let {user} = useContext(AuthContext)
    return <Route {...rest}>{!user ? <Navigate to="/login" /> : children}</Route>
}

export default PrivateRoute`

I get this error
ERROR: [PrivateRoute] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>
